# PHP How to round decimal numbers up?

Tags: php, rounding

I would like to round my decimal number.

As I search on tutorial, We can use `round` function.

Example I have this number `7.1`, when I tried to round it using

```
echo round("7.1");
```

It will show us: `7`

But now I want if `7.1` it should be `8`. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend the `ceil` function which will round the number up to the nearest value.

```
echo ceil('7.1');
```

Answer (score 2):

There is 3 rounding functions: `ceil`, `floor`, `round`.

Ceil will round numbers up. [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)

Floor will round numbers down. [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)

Round will round following basic rounding rules. 0.5 and higher rounds up. 0.4 and lower rounds down. [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)